# Let $H$ be self-adjoint matrix of size $n$. Assume $tr H^{3}=tr H^{2}=tr H= 1$. Prove there's unit vector $u\in \mathbf{C}^{n}$ s.t. $H=u u^{*}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

**Problem:** Let $H$ be a self-adjoint matrix of size $n$. Assume that $\operatorname{tr} H^{3}=\operatorname{tr} H^{2}=\operatorname{tr} H=1 $. Prove that there is a unit vector $u=\left(\begin{array}{c}\alpha_{1} \\ \vdots \\ \alpha_{n}\end{array}\right) \in \mathbf{C}^{n}$ such that $H=u u^{*}$.
( To remind you, given a matrix $A=\left(a_{i, j}\right)$ of order $n$, we define $\operatorname{tr}(A)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i, i} .$ It satisfies the two properties $\operatorname{tr}(A+B)=\operatorname{tr} A+\operatorname{tr} B$, and $\operatorname{tr}(A B)=\operatorname{tr}(B A)$ ).

**Official solution:**
We recall the following facts about self-adjoint matrices. First, all of their eigenvalues are real numbers. Second it can be diagonalized using a unitary matrix. In other words, there is a unitary matrix $U$, and a diagonal matrix $D$ such that $H=U D U^{-1}=U D U^{*}$. Let $\lambda_{1}, \ldots, \lambda_{n}$ denote the eigenvalues of $H$ including multiplicity. Thus,
$$
D=\left(\begin{array}{llll}
\lambda_{1} & & & \\
& \lambda_{2} & & \\
& & \ddots & \\
& & & \lambda_{n}
\end{array}\right)
$$
Then, it follows from the property $\operatorname{tr}(A B)=\operatorname{tr}(B A)$, that $\operatorname{tr} U D U^{-1}=\operatorname{tr} D$. Also, since for all $k$ we have $H^{k}=U D^{k} U^{-1}$, then $\operatorname{tr} H^{k}=\operatorname{tr} U D^{k} U^{-1}=\operatorname{tr} D^{k}$. Thus, we may assume that $\operatorname{tr} D^{3}=\operatorname{tr} D^{2}=\operatorname{tr} D=1$. This is the same as $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_{i}^{3}=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_{i}^{2}=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_{i}=1$.

For all $1 \leq i \leq n$ we have $\lambda_{i}^{2} \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_{i}^{2}=1$. Hence $\lambda_{i}^{2} \leq 1$ or $-1 \leq \lambda_{i} \leq 1$. ( Remember that $\lambda_{i}$ are all real numbers ). The condition $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_{i}^{3}=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_{i}^{2}$ implies that
$$
0=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_{i}^{2}-\sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_{i}^{3}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\lambda_{i}^{2}-\lambda_{i}^{3}\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_{i}^{2}\left(1-\lambda_{i}\right)
$$
Since $\lambda_{i}^{2}\left(1-\lambda_{i}\right) \geq 0$ for all $i$ ( recall that $-1 \leq \lambda_{i} \leq 1$ ), we obtain that $\lambda_{i}^{2}\left(1-\lambda_{i}\right)=0$ for all $i$. Hence, $\lambda_{i}=0,1$ for all $i$. Since $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_{i}=1$, we deduce that exactly one of the $\lambda_{i}$ 's is one and all the others are zero. Thus, in the above matrix $D$, we may assume that $\lambda_{1}=1$ and $\lambda_{i}=0$ for all $i \geq 2$. Let $u$ denote the first column of $U$. Since $U$ is unitary, we have $(u, u)=1$ where $(\cdot, \cdot)$ is the standard inner product defined on $\mathbf{C}^{n}$. A simple matrix multiplication implies that $H=U D U^{*}=u u^{*}$.

**My question:**
I have understood everything except the line where it says
"Since $\lambda_{i}^{2}\left(1-\lambda_{i}\right) \geq 0$ for all $i$ ( recall that $-1 \leq \lambda_{i} \leq 1$ ), we obtain that $\lambda_{i}^{2}\left(1-\lambda_{i}\right)=0$ for all $i$."
I haven't fully understood why $\lambda_{i}^{2}\left(1-\lambda_{i}\right)=0$ for all $i$. If I were to suppose for the sake of contradiction that there exists index $\tau$ s.t. $\lambda_\tau^{2}\left(1-\lambda_\tau\right)>0$ then how do I find the contradiction? I don't see it.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: If $\lambda_\tau^2(1-\lambda_\tau) > 0$ for some $\tau$, then $\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i^2(1-\lambda_i) > 0$ (since all the terms in the sum are $\ge 0$, and at least one is $>0$), contradiction.

Comment: I still don't see the contradiction to the fact that $ \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i^2(1-\lambda_i) \geq 0 $. If  $\lambda_\tau^2(1-\lambda_\tau) > 0$ for some $ \tau $ then it still remains that $ \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i^2(1-\lambda_i) \geq 0 $

Comment: But the sum is not just $\ge 0$, it is $=0$ (see the equation right above "Since $\lambda_i^2(1-\lambda_i) \ge 0$ for all $i$).

Comment: Thank you, now I understand!